# window.fireEvent and window.dispatchEvent are both undefined in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've just discovered that both `window.fireEvent` and `window.dispatchEvent` are undefined in IE8, however `document.fireEvent` exists.

So how on earth do I trigger events for the `window` element in IE8?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible. The way jQuery etc does this is by virtually emitting events within jQuery, rather than using the native event emitting.